# Get a callback on a frame apparition

Tags: ros, filter, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I would like to get a callback when I got a specific frame.

I already test this method but it requires a defaut topic that i don't require:

```
point_sub_.subscribe(nh_, "scan", 10);
tf_filter_ = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(point_sub_, tf_, "laser", 10);
tf_filter_->registerCallback( boost::bind(&TeleopRoboteq::msgCallback, this, _1) );
```

Can I subscribe to tf and trigger the message filter like a normal topic (instead of laser in my exemple)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220102/get-a-callback-on-a-frame-apparition/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what you mean by "triggering the message filter like a normal topic". You can use the MessageFilter for any topic with a Header.

You can also create a `tf::MessageFilter` with an unused topic and programatically add data to it via it's API.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-10-30**:
Actually I don't need any topic beside tf. I have to do a transform when a frame appear. it look like I need a mix between messagefilter and waitfortransform.